# Not able to emit an event to a parent component from child component in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My parent component takes data which is an array of strings from the api  and then passes it to the child component. In the child component I display the data from the parent as a dropdown list and when I select a particular item from the dropdown list I want it to set a particular variable.
I have used $emit and $event as shown in documentation but it is not working.Please look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong.

Parent Component App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <nlp-vision-catalog v-bind:cataloglist="catalogs"  v-on:listenClick="setcatalogselected($event)" ></nlp-vision-catalog>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import NlpVisionCatalog from './components/NlpVisionCatalog'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            NlpVisionCatalog
        },
        data (){
            return {
            catalogs :[],
            catalog_selected : ""
        }
    },
    methods:{
        fetchcatalogs(){
                axios.get("http://localhost:5000/clients")
                .then((resp)=>{this.catalogs.push.apply(this.catalogs,
                   resp.data.response.results.client_name);
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err);
                })
        },
        setcatalogselected(catalog){
        this.catalog_selected = catalog;
    )}
},
    created(){
        this.fetchcatalogs()
    }
}
</script>
<style></style>
```

My Child Component is NlpVisionCatalog.vue

```
enter code here
<template>
<div>
    <h3>Select Catalog</h3>
    <select>
        <option v-for="item in cataloglist">
            <p v-on:click="emitbackthecatalog(item)"> {{ item }} </p>
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name : 'NlpVisionCatalog',
    props: ['cataloglist'],
    data (){
        return {
            comp: ""
        }
    },
    methods:{
        emitbackthecatalog(catalog_name){
            this.$emit('listenClick',catalog_name);
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Where exactly I am going wrong?
ps- http://localhost:5000/clients is the api that is running on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your child component select element

change your code to like this use onChange function in select element

```
 <h3>Select Catalog</h3>
    <select v-model="selected" v-on:change="emitbackthecatalog(selected)">
        <option v-for="item in cataloglist" :value="item" :key="item" >
           {{ item }}
        </option>
    </select>



data (){
    return {
        selected: ""
    }
  },
  methods:{
    emitbackthecatalog(catalog_name){
        this.$emit('listenclick',catalog_name);
    }
  }
```

In your parent component

```
<nlp-vision-catalog v-bind:cataloglist="catalogs"  v-on:listenclick="setcatalogselected($event)" ></nlp-vision-catalog>
```

check the demo [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nspmqu3z/)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
That worked :)
Can you please explain why my way was failing and your way actually worked.
I am new to Vuejs.

Comment: select element needs an value to be binded for binding we have to use v-model. Then only we will get what value is selected. And also select element triggers onchange function when each time the option element is change it will emit an listenclick to parent component

Comment: One last question.
You have used v-bind:value="item" and v-bind:key="item" .
Why exactly have you used that?
Is it to be used everytime when we use v-for directive

Comment: v-bind:value is not needed in every case if you use array of object in v-for then it is necessary. v-bind:key is necessary one. it will renderer the dom correctly even the array value change or deleted. you can check this [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)